# Django - Ajax or not Ajax?

Tags: python, django, ajax

**EDIT**
below what I have done but even if my ajax seems correct, my navbar is not updated with result of the ajax request

**urls.py**

```
app_name='randomization'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('stock/', views.stock, name='stock'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def stock(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        site = request.POST['site']
    else:
        site = ''

    # database queries to be done after
    # result will be stock == True or stock == False

    return render(request, 'randomization/stock.html', {'stock': True})
```

**ajax code**

```
        $("#site").on("change", function(event){

            console.log($(this).val());

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{% url "randomization:stock" %}',
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    'site' : $(this).val(), 
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    // alert(data) -> OK
                    if (data) {
                        // alert("Test retour requete ajax"); -> OK
                        $("#alerte").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

**ajax template**

```
{% if stock %}
    <a class="nav-link" id="informations" href="#" style="color:red; padding-right: 50px;"><strong>Insufficient stock</strong></a>
{% else %}

{% endif %}
```

```
<li class="nav-item" id="alerte">
    // ajax template to be added
</li>
```

**So I do not understand why it doesn't add the message 'insufficient stock'?**

.
.
.

I have a Django project with a classical navabar which contain a select and other link with dropdownmenu

I have a function that query the database to control drug stocks in a center (user's center - CHU by default - or center selected) and return a bool
if true, the red alert 'Insufficient stock' is display and link 'Randomize a patient' and 'Reallocate a patient' should not be display

I would like drug stock to be reevaluated when user select another center without reloading the page
I think I should use ajax but I am lost on how to implement

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you google your problem?

Comment: before asking question I suggest to read and google it,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKSNciGr8kY
https://realpython.com/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/
their are a lot of you tube video and tutorial about Ajax and Django.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ajax for this purpose.

```js
        $.ajax({
            url: "Your URL",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                Data1: 'something',
                Data2: 'something else',
            }
        });
```

Don't forget to add `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in your query's data.

Answer (score 0):

pleas use google and google your question before asking in community.
there are a lot of tutorial for Ajax and using it python.
look at the links below, start by Django doc site it self.
the only way to interact with your django DB and your website with out reloading the page  is using AJAX.

[Django and AJAX](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX)

[how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html)

[Django And Ajax Full Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHh6aDRpIx4)

Answer (score 0):

finally it works, problem come from commented lines in my code that seems to be interpreted ???
but a great thanks to both !